# If a Christmas question is aware of itself, would it be ethical close it on Philsophy meta on Christmas?

Tags: discussion

If a question was written to wish "Merry Christmas to all" on Philosophy meta, but was aware of its own existence and its ability to "die" if closed, would it be ethical to downvote it or close it?

As a secondary question: could it wish a group of philsophers on Philosophy meta happy holidays regardless of religion or belief without being deemed "too broad?"

:)

Comment: Happy holidays everyone!

Comment: You too, mate! :) For things like this, remember [there's also chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium)!